# What is the variable of $#?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, parameter

I'm learning introductory Linux and came across something which I did not understand:
"The following command has been executed:

```
set 10 20 30 40 50
```

Enter the value of the variable `$#`:

I understand that the variables `$1=10 $2=20` and so on. So what would `$#` be?

Comment: 5 - or a count of elements in the `$@` shell array.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the following bash :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $#
```

And you run such as : `./arg.sh g jt t uu`

It return 4, 4 is number of argument that you pass to your shell.

It's very good to investigate your parameters of your shell script.

 Supppose i have the following usage of program :
`--value PATTERN -o PS_COMMAND_OPTIONS`

Then  I can investigate such as the following code:

```
if [ "$1" = "--value" -a "$3" != "-o"  -o "$1" != "--value" -a "$3" = "-o" -o ! $# -eq 4 ]; then
    help;
    exit;
fi;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing introductory Linux as also. I see where it means total number of arguments.
 You can use it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# = 2 ]
    then echo "Your name is $1 $2"
else
    echo "You need two arguments"
fi
```